# 403 Access Denied status code in a HTTP request

Tags: python, web-scraping

I've tried every other post similiar to this, nothing worked, it works fine sometimes but then it just gives me this error, I have set the User-Agent AND I am using a requests session,

```
import requests

requestHeaders = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.89 Safari/537.36',
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'Referer': 'https://www.dell.com/support/home/en-us?app=warranty',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
    'TE': 'Trailers',
    'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
}

session = requests.Session()
a = session.get("url", headers=requestHeaders)
print(a.status_code)
```

This code returns 403 Access Denied, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The code works for me. Probably they banned you while testing or there is a different problem with your access to the web.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with your headers. With the usage of these, I could get a `200` status code.

```
headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.76 Safari/537.36",
    "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1",
    "DNT": "1",
    "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8",
    "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5",
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate",
}
```